# I wonder how to design a good database that sorts data when inserting values in the middle or top

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a lot of data and I need to sort the data by reflecting it when the value is added in the middle or top.
For example, a table with increasing data *(`group_order`)* is shown below.

```
code|  group_id  | group_order | depth
----+------------+-------------+-------
 c1 | Group1     |           1 |     1
                                         <-  c6 | Group1     |           2 |     1
 c2 | Group1     |           2 |     1
 c3 | Group1     |           3 |     1
 c4 | Group1     |           4 |     1
 c5 | Group1     |           5 |     1
```

As above table, I put data with *`group_order`* of 2 in the second row, and tried to increase the *`group_order`* of the data below *(c2, c3, c4, c5)* by 1.
Of course, it runs well, but as I said before, it took a lot of time to update because I have a lot of data.
When I insert the data into the desired location, the values should be sorted in that order.
Please help me.

The database I use is **`postgresql`**.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot. By design tables are **unordered collections**. You cannot get a deterministic order without specifying *order by* in the query. Further consider  it for a minuet, even if this was doable you would not want it. Image a multiple user environment with several users inserting into this table and on average having to rewrite half the table on each insert. Also, what happens when the group_order of a particular row is updated. If you want to present in a specific order then create a **view* which contains the order by.

Answer (score -1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M3aSc3v0)

I personally think, it is never a good idea to manipulate the internal data for such reasons as sort order or similar. Final order is something for the view and not for the model. So in my opinion you should think about calculating the order when you need it, not generally. Another problem could be the inserting performance, which I am not quite sure about, but should be investigated: As you will update all your data, the records will be blocked by the transaction and in that time you will not be able to insert another record. If no blocking transaction, you should think about race conditions (what happens if two records will be inserted simultaneously?).

I would introduce a second sort column like an insert number which stores the number at which the record was inserted. Could be simply a serial or auto-increment sequence.

And then you could simply order by `group_order ASC` followed by `insert_nr DESC`. Benefit: You don't need to manipulate your original data.

If you still need a correct order number, you could create a (materialized) view and add the order number with incrementing numbers using `row_number()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html).

Introducing an (auto-)incrementing column `insert_nr`:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    code text,
    group_order int,
    insert_nr serial
);
```

Using it within a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_myview AS

SELECT
    code, group_order,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY group_order, insert_nr DESC)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM mytable
) s;
```

Comment: Thank you for your good reply.

However, this seems to be a way to allow newly inserted data to be sorted ahead of existing data.
I need to be able to sort behind the existing data at the same time.
If you know a good way, I would appreciate it if you could reply.

Thank you.

Comment: @JiseoupLim Your example shows c6 before c2, right? So, you want c2 before c6 instead? Just order insert_nr ASC instead DESC.

Comment: Oh! I didn't even think of such a simple problem when I looked at it.
I'm very grateful for your help.
Thank you!